# SQL query to get distinct data from a column and get rest data along in the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I might be asking this as a repeated question but please go through it once as I have tried everything and I am missing something.

```
select 

    Q.f_query_id,
    Q.cust_id,  
    Q.current_agent,
    Q.current_agent_time,
    Q.current_status,
    Q.query_type,
    Q.pax_name,
    Q.pax_no,
    Q.pax_email,
    Q.start_date,   
    Q.return_date,
    Q.origin_code,
    Q.destination_code,
    Q.adult,
    Q.child,
    Q.infant,
    Q.class,
    Q.linked_pnrs,
    Q.followup_time

from a_query Q 
inner join
(
    select MIN(cust_id) cust_id, pax_email
    from a_query where current_status = 'F'
    group by pax_email
) Q1
    on Q.cust_id = Q1.cust_id
    and Q.pax_email= Q1.pax_email
```

Please help

I have this query what I want to do is to get unique customer Id (cust_id) along with all other columns. as in the data there is lot of cust_id which are repeated many times at the same time I also wanted to use where clause on one column (current_status) to get the desired result.

so the psuedo code is like this

```
 select * from a_query where cust_id is unique and status = 'f'
```

sample table

```
f_query_id  cust_id  current_status ......    pax_email
1          1              F               abc@gmail.com
2          2              B               xyz@gmail.com
3          1              F               abc@gmail.com
```

Desired result

```
f_query_id  cust_id  current_status ......    pax_email
1          1              F               abc@gmail.com
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: use distinct for cust_id

Comment: There's no `current_status` column in `Q1`, so what is `Q.current_status = Q1.current_status` supposed to match?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you show sample data and desired result?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón, there is no such thing as "distinct for cust_id"...

Comment: distinct cust_id should do fine, but since you say you have tried many things I'm sure you need something that isn't clear in the question. Best option is to give sample data and desired result as @barmar as commented

Comment: @Krishnakumar What do you mean by "distinct cust_id`? The `DISTINCT` modifier applies to the entire `SELECT` list, not a specific column.

Comment: @Barmar My understanding of his question is to get  - as he has quoted  - Unique cust_id along with the other columns...

Comment: But I hope it isn't. He needs something else and he says he has tried many things.

Comment: Then maybe it should be `GROUP BY cust_id`, that's how you make a single column unique.

Comment: Can a customer have many status = f ?

Comment: Thanks to all. sorry I am new to stackoverflow so don't know how to show code and columns. Here is my query once again as most of answers asked about  it. I have a table with above mentioned columns eg Q.cust_id. what i need to do is to write a query which will return all the columns with unique Cust_ID and associated data with a condition on a column "current_status" and "followup_time".  remember there are multiple rows in that table containing same cust_Ids (just fr reference f_query_id is primary key). Please let me know if that makes sense

Comment: @barmar my bad.. current_status was another field which I was testing while joining the data. please ignore.

Comment: Check the answer below (MySql part), it will solve your problem

Comment: In your table, `cust_id` is the same for the same `pax_email`. How should it decide which of the two rows to return the unique data from?

Comment: @barmar. you got the point.. exactly this is what I am looking for, and I do have other table where i have this customer_ID (cust_id) field which is primary key. this is where I am stuck what and how to use it. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you doing `MIN(cust_id)` if it's always the same `cust_id`? If there are multiple rows with the same `cust_id` and same `pax_email`, how should it decide which row to return? Is there another field that it can use to prioritize?

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much for figuring out what was wrong. you made my day :) I was using the wrong column all the time using MIN(f_query_id) with some modifications sorted this all out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (For SQL Server)

```
;WITH commonTableExpression AS(
SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by cust_id ORDER BY cust_id)  rowNumber
FROM    a_query
WHERE   current_status = 'F'
)
SELECT * FROM commonTableExpression WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

For MySQL

```
SELECT t.*,
       @prev_value := cust_id
FROM   a_query
WHERE  (IF(@prev_value = cust_id, @row_num + 1, 1) = 1)
       AND current_status = 'F'
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have CTE.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I have no idea about stored procedures so when I tried using your query it gave me an error "must declare the scalar variable sql" and when I used "DECLARE @prev_value nvarchar(100) " it again shows error. any alternatives? using simple queries. I would highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 

    Q.f_query_id,
    Q.cust_id,  
    Q.current_agent,
    Q.current_agent_time,
    Q.current_status,
    Q.query_type,
    Q.pax_name,
    Q.pax_no,
    Q.pax_email,
    Q.start_date,   
    Q.return_date,
    Q.origin_code,
    Q.destination_code,
    Q.adult,
    Q.child,
    Q.infant,
    Q.class,
    Q.linked_pnrs,
    Q.followup_time

from a_query Q 
inner join
(
    select MIN(f_query_id) f_query_id, pax_email
    from a_query where current_status='F'
    group by pax_email 
Having MIN(current_status)  ='F'
) Q1
    on Q.f_query_id= Q1.f_query_id
    and Q.pax_email= Q1.pax_email
```

Sorted out the matter thanks to all.